# sed delete line containg a pair of () parenthesis

Tags: sed

Hi I have created a large **set of sed commands** to manipulate a text file.
The one last thing I cant seem to solve is where a line simply consists of a pair of ()

```
some text
()
more text
(leave this line as is)
```

I want to delete the entire () line

```
some text
more text
(leave this line as is)
```

in my script
this sed command **-e '/()/ s/()//'** can find and remove the () but leaves a line behind

```
some text

more text
(leave this line as is)
```

Here is a snipped version of the bigger picture

```
FILEPATH=*.chordpro
for fn in $FILEPATH; do
    echo $fn
    fnbak=$fn.bak
    mv "$fn" "$fnbak" #Create an untouched backup

    sed `: # these are comments` \
`: # Insert after subtitle; author,book,keywords,tempo,time` \
    -e '/^{subtitle.*/a {author:mds}\n{book:CatStevens}\n{keywords:70s,Tillerman}\n{tempo:120}\n{time:4/4}' \
    -e 's/{subtitle:/{artist:/'     `: # swap subtitle for artist` \
    -e 's/{time:/{duration:/'   `: # modifiy original meta "time" for "duration"` \
....lots of other commands
    `: # Tidy up` \
        -e '/()/ s/()//'            `: # Remove any () pairs created by script`  \
         "$fnbak" >"$fn"
```

Here is snippet of the input test cases.

```
{c:Verse2}
{c: Verse 2: Bass single}
{c: Verse 2 Rock it}
{c: verse 1}
{c: verse     1}
{c: Verse 1:}
{c:Verse}
```

Here it is converted. Out#1

```
Verse 2:
()
Verse 2:
( Bass single)
Verse 2:
( Rock it)
Verse 1:
()
Verse 1:
()
Verse 1:
()
Verse :
()
```

This is the tidy up result using **-e '/()/ s/()//'** Out#2

```
Verse 2:

Verse 2:
( Bass single)
Verse 2:
( Rock it)
Verse 1:

Verse 1:

Verse 1:

Verse :
```

This is the result using **-e '/()/d'**

```
Verse 2:
( Bass single)
Verse 2:
( Rock it)
```

***where has everything after Rock it gone and why????***
NOTE: ok it has something to do with it being in the loop/interaction with other sed commands.
If I put Out#1 into a file on its own and run just the sed **-e '/()/d'** command on it, it works

This is what I hoped to achieve

```
Verse 2:
Verse 2:
( Bass single)
Verse 2:
( Rock it)
Verse 1:
Verse 1:
Verse 1:
Verse :
```

Comment: I should also mention, there are other lines using brackets i don't want to touch.
(leave this  alone)

Comment: Perhaps using `grep` e.g. `grep -v "()" file`

Comment: its part of a stack of other sed  -e commands

Comment: `sed -e '/()/d'` should do the trick

Comment: yeah thats what i thought.. it seems to also screw up a stack of other things. I cant fathom why.

Comment: Maybe try piping the data to it? E.g. `stack of sed commands "$fnbak" | sed -e '/()/d' > "$fn"` (although if you are going to do this it would make sense to use grep instead)

Comment: "Maybe try piping the data to it? E.g. stack of sed commands "$fnbak" | sed -e '/()/d' > "$fn"" "-jared_mamrot
This also actually worked. Which confirms my suspicions of weird things in the loop space.  thanks

Comment: Perhaps the problem is in the `....lots of other commands`. Can you esit a copy of your script and remove as much lines as possible where you cah still see the problem. What happens when your (modified)  script takes `Out#1` as input ?

Comment: Is `\n()` being *created* by `lots of other commands`? (as `/()/d` appears to be deleting a multiline pattern space)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including a concise, complete script (your problem is trying to write code to remove `()`s added by a script but then you don't show us a script than adds `()`s) plus sample input and expected output that demonstrates your problem and we could copy/paste to test against.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write lengthy sed scripts, use awk instead for clarity, efficiency, robustness, portability, etc. Instead of this:

```
    sed `: # these are comments` \
`: # Insert after subtitle; author,book,keywords,tempo,time` \
    -e '/^{subtitle.*/a {author:mds}\n{book:CatStevens}\n{keywords:70s,Tillerman}\n{tempo:120}\n{time:4/4}' \
    -e 's/{subtitle:/{artist:/'     `: # swap subtitle for artist` \
    -e 's/{time:/{duration:/'   `: # modifiy original meta "time" for "duration"` \
....lots of other commands
    `: # Tidy up` \
        -e '/()/ s/()//'            `: # Remove any () pairs created by script`  \
         "$fnbak" >"$fn"
```

try this which I **think** is the equivalent of what you're doing above but also fixes your code to remove `()` pairs:

```
awk '
    # Insert after subtitle; author,book,keywords,tempo,time
    /^{subtitle/ {
        $0 = $0 \
            "\n{author:mds}"              \
            "\n{book:CatStevens}"         \
            "\n{keywords:70s,Tillerman}"  \
            "\n{tempo:120}"               \
            "\n{time:4/4}"
    }

    {
        sub(/{subtitle:/,"{artist:")      # swap subtitle for artist
        sub/{time:/,"{duration:")         # modify original meta "time" for "duration"
        ....lots of other commands

        # Tidy up
        # Remove any () pairs created by script
        gsub(/\n\()\n/,"\n")              # Convert every \n()\n to \n ..
        gsub(/\n\()\n/,"\n")              # .. done twice to handle \n()\n()\n
        gsub(/^\()\n|\n\()$/,"")          # Remove ()\n at the start and \n() at the end
        gsub(/\()/,"")                    # Remove every remaining ()

        print
    }

' "$fnbak" > "$fn"
```

Your comment says `Remove any () pairs created by script` but the script you posted cannot create any `()` pairs so I'm assuming that your `lots of other commands` can do so and I'm just guessing in my awk script about what it really is you want to do in the "Tidy up" section since you didn't provide any sample input/output we could test against.

By the way, the more common way to modify an input file would be:

```
fnbak=$(mktemp) || exit 1
cmd 'script' "$fn" > "$fnbak" &&
mv -- "$fnbak" "$fn"
```

rather than

```
fnbak=$fn.bak
mv "$fn" "$fnback"
cmd 'script' "$fnbak" > "$fn"
```

The former only keeps the backup file around long enough to modify the original, only uses a single backup for all files rather than 1 per file, and won't wipe out your original input file if there isn't enough disk space or you don't have write permission to create the backup.

You only have to create the backup file once before entering your loop:

```
FILEPATH=*.chordpro
fnbak=$(mktemp) || exit 1
for fn in $FILEPATH; do
    echo "$fn"
    cmd 'script' "$fn" > "$fnbak" &&
    mv -- "$fnbak" "$fn"
done
```

but of course you don't need a loop or temp files at all if you use GNU awk, all you need is:

```
gawk -i inplace 'script' *.chordpro
```

(add `FNR==1{print FILENAME | "cat>&2"}` to the awk script to see the input file names printed as they're worked on).

Comment: thanks Ed. When I started this it was a simple swap case but then I realised how messed up my 1000 text files were. I kept falling down rabbit holes until it became beyond my scope. I  do appreciate your input. I had never used sed before now  and it looks like awk might have been a better choice. I will take some time to rethink the idea as I found even  more problems today.

Comment: for eg.. "subtitle" could be completely missing which means I have to insert it along with the other metas after title but if it is there, not loose its value...oh dear :(

Comment: I've been using sed for about 40 years, awk for about 30. sed is the right tool for doing a simple s/old/new on an individual string. For anything else, just use awk.

Answer (score 0):

here's a GNU sed script for you - it allows inline comments so there's no need for complicated quoting

Save it in tmp.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# tmp.sh

sed -E '
# strip initial piece
s/\{c: *//

# strip terminal piece
s/ *} *$//

# munge verse with number
s/verse *([0-9]+):? */Verse \1:/i

# munge verse without number
s/verse *$/Verse :/i

# put description on new line
s/: *(.+)$/:\n(\1)/
'
```

Test with heredoc:

```sh
$ ./tmp.sh <<EOF
{c:Verse2}
{c: Verse 2: Bass single}
{c: Verse 2 Rock it}
{c: verse 1}
{c: verse     1}
{c: Verse 1:}
{c:Verse}
EOF
```

```sh
Verse 2:
Verse 2:
(Bass single)
Verse 2:
(Rock it)
Verse 1:
Verse 1:
Verse 1:
Verse :
```

It's hard to say why your single delete command behaves unexpectedly without seeing the entire script

You could try the relatively new `--debug` option offered in sed 4.6 - or what I find very useful are the `l` and `=` commands to show the state of the line at any point in multiple transformations

My script is more like a starting point for you to compare and troubleshoot your script and to modify for other test cases

Hope it helps

Comment: You need to do more to anchor your regexps. For example try changing `{c: Verse 2: Bass single}` to `{c: Verse 2: Bass verse Treble}` and note that your regexps that try to replace `verse` now match that line undesirably. There are other cases where a false match can happen with your regexps. I don't know why the OP posted this as sample input anyway though since it contains none of the text that their script is operating on (e.g. `{subtitle`) - I think it's a total red herring, maybe caused by the OP over-simplifying their real data, idk.

Comment: ahh so much neater than mine. I will process your answer too.